# How can I copy all values from multiples List<DTO1> to a single List<DTO2>

Tags: java, list, collections, hashmap, java-stream

Sorry for my english!

I have three `List<DTO1>`:

```
List A:

ListA{id=5, userLogin='cdp', count=14}
ListA{id=11452, userLogin='clelonginge', count=7}
ListA{id=11451, userLogin='vdupontinge', count=16}

List B:

ListB{id=5, userLogin='cdp', count=26}
ListB{id=11452, userLogin='clelonginge', count=14}
ListB{id=11451, userLogin='vdupontinge', count=6}

List C:

ListC{id=5, userLogin='cdp', count=29}
ListC{id=11452, userLogin='clelonginge', count=45}
ListC{id=11451, userLogin='vdupontinge', count=75}
```

And i want to make a third `List<DTO2>` containing the values of the count attribute of the 3 Lists.
here is what i want:

```
List D:

ListD{id=5, userLogin='cdp', countListA=14, countListB=26, countListC=29}
ListD{id=11452, userLogin='clelonginge', countListA=7, countListB=14, countListC=45}
ListD{id=11451, userLogin='vdupontinge', countListA=16, countListB=6, countListC=75}
```

So I tried differents ways of doing, like:

```
ListC = ListA.stream().map(DTO1::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());

(it gave me the following error:

    Error:(475, 98) java: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
        equality constraints: org.ocdm.service.dto.DTO2
        lower bounds: java.lang.Long
)
```

or with a HashMap but I didn't succeed to find a solution.

**edit:**
ListA, ListB and ListC are the same type. They are of type: `List<DTO1>`.

But List D is different. It is of type: `List<DTO2>.`

DTO1 have 3 attributes: id, userLogin and count.

DT02 have 5 attributes: id, userLogin, countListA, countListB and countListC.

Comment: Are ListA, ListB, ListC different Java types?

Comment: ListA, ListB and ListC are the same type. They are of type: List<DTO1>.  But LIst D is different. It is of type: List<DTO2>.   DTO1 have 3 attributes: id, userLogin and count. DT02 have 5 attributes: id, userLogin, countListA, countListB and countListC.

Comment: I guess doing it conventionally makes sense here rather than using streams,map, and Collectors

Comment: do you mean by looping through all Lists? actually, i simplified my example so that you understand it, but my table have a lot of rows and more columns. So i think it will slow down my application.

Comment: Do you know how streams work? `ListC = ListA.stream().map(DTO1::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());` tells me you don't. Maybe start there first?

Comment: I can't even understand what you are trying to do. Try to implement without streams first if you are not familiar with them. Also, please update your question to show what you have already tried in a
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),
and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you know that `id` is unique (there no two `id`s with different `userLogin`s) then map as an intermediate could help.

At first, you have to create map from one list. Let's say it's `listA`:

```
Map<Integer, DTO2> map = listA.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(item->item.getId(),
                item->new DTO2(item.getId(), item.getUserLogin(), item.getCount(), 0,0)));
```

Note, I suppose you have constructor `DTO2(Integer id, String userLogin, Integer countListA, Integer countListB, Integer countListC)`.

Second, you add all items from `listB` using [Map.merge()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-). If map has no key then it creates a new entry.  If map has key equals to itemB.id then it updates value. Note that constructor receive countB as 4th parameter.

```
listB.forEach(itemB -> map.merge(
            // key for our map
            itemB.getId(),
            // function to create new entry if no such key
            new DTO2(itemB.getId(), itemB.getUserLogin(), 0, itemB.getCount(),0),
            //function to update
            (existed, noMatter) -> {
                existed.setCountListB(itemB.getCount());
                return existed;
            }));
```

Note that `merge()` need a function. If `item.setCountListB()` returns nothing then you need explicitly return value in third argument. As an alternative, you could declare it as `DTO2 setCountListB()` - which is unusual but possible.

Then merge the last list. Note that we pass count as 5th argument in constructor.

```
listC.forEach(itemC -> map.merge(
            itemC.getId(),
            new DTO2(itemC.getId(), itemC.getUserLogin(), 0, 0,itemC.getCount()),
            (existingItem, noMatter) -> {existingItem.setCountListC(itemC.getCount()); return existingItem;}));
```

And finally, return `List` instead of `Map`

```
return map.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that code rely that constructor receives `countA`, `countB` and `countC` in specific order. It's could be confusing and probably you want to use a builder pattern but it's out of scope.

---

The code probably is not perfect from perspective of performance but you got the idea.

Comment: ok thank you ADS. I am going to try what you just told me! wish you the best!

Comment: @sinaardehali You're welcome. Don't forget accept answer if it solved your problem